# Почему происходит ошибка при попытке подключиться к интернету

Tags: java, android

Когда я запускаю `HttpURLConnection` происходит фатальная ошибка

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 1754
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3448)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3595)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7814)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1565)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:115)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1152)
        at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:41)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:178)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:144)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:86)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:192)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:144)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:106)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:400)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:333)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:483)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:429)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:252)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:211)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
        at com.example.myapplication.fore.doInBackground(fore.java:17)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:101)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7955)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7944)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3423)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3595) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7814) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

Сам метод в котором происходит ошибка:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Background extends Service {

    final String LOG_TAG = "gradle";

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate");
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStartCommand");
        try {
            send("https://cake.000webhostapp.com/?php=stack");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDestroy");
    }

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onBind");
        return null;
    }

    public static void send(String request) throws Exception {

        URL url = new URL(request);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");
        connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
        connection.connect();
        Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

        for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0;){
            System.out.print((char)c);
        }
    }
}
```

Извините за возможно глупые вопросы, совсем недавно начал программировать на Java и Android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetworkOnMainThreadException говорит вам о том, что соединение с сетью надо запускать не в основном потоке.  Так же надо добавить разрешение в манифест

Comment: Такое ? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`